# Remove Icon on Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add an icon to a button when it is active and it can change every time that an other item is clicked.

It does not change when I want it to change the active button I have to refresh the page to solve it.

```
<div id="a" class="pipeline-modal-content">
    <button>
        <span>name 1</span>
    </button>
    <span id="b"></span>
</div>
<div id="a" class="pipeline-modal-content">
    <button>
        <span>name 2</span>
    </button>
    <span id="b"></span>
</div>
```

---

```
var a = $("#a");
var b = $("#b");
a.click(function () {
    $('#b').html('&#10004;');
});
$('#b').on('click', function () {
    $(this).closest("#b").remove();
});
```

Comment: `id`s within the document are supposed to be unique. Also, you probably don't want to remove the element, rather change the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following snippet. If you prefer to use JQuery just replace

`document.getElementById('button1')` by `$("#button1")`

`button1.addEventListener('click',` by `button1.on('click',`;

`button1.innerHTML = ''` by `button1.html('')`

```js
var button1 = document.getElementById('button1');
var button2 = document.getElementById('button2');
var check1 = document.getElementById('check1');
var check2 = document.getElementById('check2');

button1.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if (check1.innerHTML) {
        check1.innerHTML = '';
        return;
    }
    check1.innerHTML = '✓';
    check2.innerHTML = '';
});

button2.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if (check2.innerHTML) {
        check2.innerHTML = '';
        return;
    }
    check1.innerHTML = '';
    check2.innerHTML = '✓';
});
```

```html
<div class="pipeline-modal-content">
    <button id="button1">
        <span>name 1</span>
    </button>
    <span id="check1"></span>
</div>
<div id="a" class="pipeline-modal-content">
    <button id="button2">
        <span>name 2</span>
    </button>
    <span id="check2"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by deselect buttons? Second click on the same button should deselect it?

Comment: can i do this for styles? i have a style for button1 when i click on it,its font will change but i want that second click on it disable this style.

Answer (score 0):

updated @vladislav question, so here it is in native js:

```js
var button1 = document.getElementById('button1');
var button2 = document.getElementById('button2');
var check1 = document.getElementById('check1');
var check2 = document.getElementById('check2');

button1.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    // check if already has ✓ letter
    if ( check1.innerHTML === '✓' ) {
       check1.innerHTML = '';
       return;
    }         
      check1.innerHTML = '✓';
      check2.innerHTML = '';
    
});

button2.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    // check if already has ✓ letter
    if ( check2.innerHTML === '✓' ) {
       check2.innerHTML = '';
       return;
    }
    
    check1.innerHTML = '';
    check2.innerHTML = '✓';
});
```

```html
<div class="pipeline-modal-content">
    <button id="button1">
        <span>name 1</span>
    </button>
    <span id="check1"></span>
</div>
<div id="a" class="pipeline-modal-content">
    <button id="button2">
        <span>name 2</span>
    </button>
    <span id="check2"></span>
</div>
```

and also `jQuery` answer, cause you have `jquery` tag in your question:

```js
$('#button1').on('click', function(){

    if( $('#check1').html() == '✔' ){
        $('#check1').html('');
        return;
    }
    
    $('#check1').html('✔');
    $('#check2').html('');
});

$('#button2').on('click', function(){

    if( $('#check2').html() == '✔' ){
        $('#check2').html('');
        return;
    }
    
    $('#check2').html('✔');
    $('#check1').html('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pipeline-modal-content">
    <button id="button1">
        <span>name 1</span>
    </button>
    <span id="check1"></span>
</div>
<div id="a" class="pipeline-modal-content">
    <button id="button2">
        <span>name 2</span>
    </button>
    <span id="check2"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: its correct answer but i want to put a <img/> instead of check icon how i can do this?your code not work for img tag.

Comment: @Aref.Heydari please read the rules of stack overflow, you ask question, i'm post answer, you check as answer, and then cancel it and check another, and after that you want any help?